# How can I connect SonarQube and GitLab?

Tags: java, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I installed **GitLab** and also **Sonar Qube**.

Now I want connect each other, I would like to obtain something like: "when I push the code, I want run sonar to analyze the code"...

I searched only but I don't find anything... Could you explain if it is possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a piece in the middle (Jenkins, TeamCity, Bamboo, VSTS, ...) to notice that there has been a commit, check out the code, build it, and run the analysis.

Comment: ok, so I install Jenkins for example, and after that what shall I do?? I means,  do any plugins exist (or something else) that permit to connect them?

Comment: Gitlab has built-in CI. It can integrate with Jenkins and others but additional software is not needed.